# How to generate a Extent cucumber report in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, cucumber

i have my automation script written in 'Ruby', How do we generate a extent report in ruby. i'am using eclipse to write my script.

Comment: What is extent report? Its related to cucumber question?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible as Extent only supports Java and .Net as of version 3.  The upcoming version 4 will initially be released for Java only.

Also, the Extent Cucumber plugin is Java only.

Comment: Is there a way I can enhance my html report ??? .I want a report similar to extent . Any ruby code that I can add in my feature file or my step definition

Comment: See here: https://github.com/anshooarora/extentreports-java/issues/168#issuecomment-164575118. You can use the code written by the owner and customize it further. It is pure Ruby. There was no contribution from the community so the Ruby binding was shut down.